# Stokes Theorem (Application)

Tags: proof-verification, vector-analysis

**Statement:** If a vector field R is irrotational then a line integral is independent of path.

*Proof.* Let $\nabla$ $\times$ $\vec A=0$ in $R$ consider the difference of two line integral from the point $r_0$ to $r$ along two curves $C_1$ & $C_2$.

[image]
$$\int_{C_1} \vec A.dr_1 -\int_{C_2} \vec A.dr_2$$

where $r_1$ is integration variable to distinguish it from the limit of integration $r$ &$r_0$

now $$\int_{C} \vec A.dr_1 =  \int_{C_1} \vec A.dr_1 -\int_{C_2} \vec A.dr_2$$

from Stokes theorem $\int_{C} \vec A.dr_1$ =$\int_{S} \nabla \times \vec A.\vec ds $

$\nabla \times \vec A=0 $

so $\int_{C} \vec A.dr_1=0$

Is there any mistake?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please typeset your question. These photos are barely readable. Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/4583).

Comment: One thing that is wrong is that the man's name was Stokes, not Stoke.

Comment: It depends on what level student you are. How do you know an arbitrary closed curve bounds an *orientable* surface $S$?

Comment: OK sorry. Any mathematical mistake?

Comment: surface integral of curl A over an open surface S is bounded by C